# Trying to categorize

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I am building an application about facts. I have created different buttons for different activities where I have my facts presented in textview. I have created different text files in assets from where the facts are picked. The problem is that everytime I tap on the button my application crashes. Help me guys...

My xml code

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:id="@+id/n"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="35dp" />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:background="@drawable/boombuttonnext"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/prev"
    android:background="@drawable/backk"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

My Java code

```
public class MainActivity22Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton btn,prev;
    TextView tc;
    ArrayList<String> listOfFacts;
    int position = 0;

    void init()
    {
        listOfFacts = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            InputStream is =  getAssets().open("boom.txt");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line ;
            while( (line =  in.readLine())   != null)
                listOfFacts.add(line);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();




        position =   getSharedPreferences("storage" ,1).getInt("pos",0);


        btn  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        prev  = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.prev);
        tc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b);

        tc.setText("" + listOfFacts.get(position));





        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {



                position++;

                if(listOfFacts.size()==position)
                    position = 0;

                tc.setText("" + listOfFacts.get(position));


            }
        });

        prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                position--;

                if(position<0)
                    position = listOfFacts.size()-1;

                tc.setText("" + listOfFacts.get(position));

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getSharedPreferences("storage" ,1).edit().putInt("pos" , position).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does it crash? Please post your stack trace

Comment: W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c19ae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-05 23:50:59.277    2105-2105/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-05 23:51:01.432    2105-2128/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-05 23:51:01.432    2105-2128/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa6c19ae0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
06-05 23:51:09.533    2105-2114/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist W/art﹕

Comment: Suspending all threads took: 14.965ms
06-05 23:51:12.128    2105-2105/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
    --------- beginning of crash
06-05 23:51:12.145    2105-2105/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: bollywoodfacts.checkinglist, PID: 2105
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{bollywoodfacts.checkinglist/bollywoodfacts.checkinglist.MainActivity2Activity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
           Here is my logcat

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

Comment: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
            at bollywoodfacts.checkinglist.MainActivity2Activity.onCreate(MainActivity2Activity.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)

Comment: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Comment: It would be much better to add the stack trace to your question (which you can always **edit**), instead of using comments.

Comment: All that logcat is useless, give us only the error part (in android studio, it's colored in dark red)

Answer (score 0):

From the output of your logcat, there is a problem when your access your array. Make sure the index to get the element from the array is not out of boundary.

> >
>   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255) at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308) at bollywoodfacts.checkinglist.MainActivity2Activity.onCreate(MainActivity2Activity‌​.java:63) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)

```
tc.setText("" + listOfFacts.get(position));
```

Comment: @AkshayRathee check the index is inside the boundary before use it.